# Вопрос по static полю

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, в процессе изучения стал вопрос: что в данном кусочке играет собой статик и почему без него этот код не работает?

```
public class test {
public test(int a, int b){
    this.a=a;
    this.b=b;
    count++;
}

public static int count=0; // вот в этом месте убрав static будет ошибка
private int a,b;
public static void main(String[] args){
    test t1 = new test(1,2);
    System.out.println(test.count);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном кусочке static служит для того, чтобы подсчитать кол-во вызовов конструктора test. Статические поля существуют в единственном экземпляре в не зависимости от кол-ва объектов класса и присваивание другого значения в одном объекте класса сразу видно и в остальных, тоесть это общее поле для всех объектов класса.

Comment: В принципе, я понимаю назначение static'a, но я не понимаю, почему в данном случае без него работать не хочет, т.е. "public int count=0;" ошибка

Comment: @111xbot111 ошибка у вас будет вовсе не в той строке, на которую вы указываете, а в вызове System.out.println(test.count), потому что убрав static вы должны использовать для обращения переменной не имя класса, а имя переменой, т.е. t1.

Comment: Ну насчет этого Вам написал @Free_ze Полный код http://ideone.com/pGZ7eh (вместо test класс Ideone) Если просто убрать static получим:

    Main.java:21: error: non-static variable count cannot be referenced from a static context
     System.out.println(Ideone.count);

Что в переводе: На нестатическую переменную count нельзя ссылаться из статического контекста.
Тоесть, для того, чтобы обратиться к нестатической переменной, нужно к ней обращаться из объекта класса(t1.Ideone), а не просто от имени класса (Ideone.count)

Comment: @a_gura опередил :)

Answer (score 2):

В статическом методе (main) напрямую можно обращаться только к статическим членам класса.
Все будет честно, если исправить на:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    test t1 = new test(1,2);
    System.out.println(t1.count); // <----here
}
```